# Mongoose module find method is not working and throwing -> "TypeError : cursor.toArray is not a function" along with "MongoInvalidArgument Error"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem in **retrieving data** from mongodb DATABASE installed locally on the computer using **mongoose module** of Nodejs.

Here is my code for **saving data** into the mongodb database that is working correctly.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB', { useNewUrlParser: true })

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number
})

const Fruit = mongoose.model('Fruit', fruitSchema)

const banana = new Fruit({
    name: "Banana",
    price: 40
})

const Apple = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    price: 30
})

banana.save()
Apple.save()
```

Data is saved into the database by using the above code but when I use the following code in the same file, it **does not output the data** on the console rather throw an error.

```
Fruit.find(function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(docs);
    }
});
```

I had tried a lot by mentioning parameters in one/two curly braces after find method but error remains the same. I had also tried .exec(function ....) but that too not worked.
Following errors comes out :

**TypeError : cursor.toArray is not a function.**

**MongoInvalidArgumentError**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5SAn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in mongoose version 6.0.1. Here is to solve this.

To work around this issue, we have to use await mongoose.connect() to wait for Mongoose to connect before calling find().

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

saveData().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function saveData() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB');

  const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model('Fruit', fruitSchema)

const banana = new Fruit({
    name: "Banana",
    price: 40
})

const Apple = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    price: 30
})

banana.save()
Apple.save()

const docs = await Fruit.find();
console.log(docs);
}

app.listen(5000)
```